# Python: Output all unique combinations with a constraint, to a Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

You'll have to forgive me as I'm currently learning Python. I have a `Pandas` `DataFrame` with the following worker attribute columns: Name, Position, HourlyPay.

**df**

```
Index   Name     Position      HourlyPay
  0     John     Analyst         15.00
  1     Mike     Programmer      18.00
  2     Lisa     Supervisor      16.75
  4     Frank    Analyst         15.50
```

I want to output to another `DataFrame` (like below) with all possible unique combinations of `n` person team, which would also include their 
positions as column headers, and another column that sums up their `HourlyPay`, then sort by highest `TotalHourlyPay`.

**uniqueDf**

```
Index   Analyst  Programmer  Supervisor  TotalHourlyPay
 0       Frank      Mike       Lisa          50.25
 1       John       Mike       Lisa          49.75
```

I used 3 positions for my example `uniqueDf` above, but at times this could change. For instance 2 `Analyst` positions could work at the same time, so I want to have the option to dynamically add or remove multiple position columns when I need to. A second example is below.

**secondExampleDf**

```
Index   Analyst  Analyst Programmer  Supervisor  TotalHourlyPay
 0       Frank    John      Mike       Lisa          65.25
```

This is a very simple example of a much larger dataset. I've attempted this problem but my code is not really worth showing. The closest I got was using `itertools.combinations` on the `df.Name` column. I attempted to append and sum a `TotalHourlyPay` column by using `join` or `merge` between the two `DataFrame`s, but I could also not get that to work.

```
possibleCombinations = list(itertools.combinations(df.Name, 3))
uniqueDf = pd.DataFrame(possibleCombinations,columns=['Employee1','Employee2','Employee3'])
```

I'm really just asking if someone could help point me in the right direction. I know SO isn't about writing the code for you, which I definitely do not want. I'm really just confused on what to do next, every link on Google Chrome is highlighted from being clicked. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code gives the result you want:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

# definition of dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
df["Index"] = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10]
df["Name"] = ["John", "Mike", "Lisa", "Franck", "Peter", "Suzanne", "Laura", "Sam", "Manon"]
df["Position"] = ["Analyst", "Programmer", "Supervisor", "Analyst", "Programmer", "Programmer", "Supervisor", "Analyst", "Analyst"]
df["HourlyPay"] = [15.00, 18.00, 16.75, 15.50, 17.00, 18.00, 16.00, 12.00, 13.00]

# dict of dataframes by position
unique_positions = list(df["Position"].unique())
pos_dfs = {}
for pos in unique_positions:
    pos_dfs[pos] = df.loc[df["Position"]==pos].reset_index()

# required positions with count
req_pos_count = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({"count":{"Analyst": 2, "Supervisor": 1, "Programmer": 1}})
req_pos_unique = list(req_pos_count.index.unique())
req_pos_dfs = [pos_dfs[pos] for pos in req_pos_unique]

which_pos = [item for _, row in req_pos_count.iterrows() for item in [row.name]*row["count"]]
which_pos_count = [str(i) + "_" + pos for i, pos in enumerate(which_pos)]

# combinations
pos_dfs_rows = [list(itertools.combinations(range(len(pos_df)), req_pos_count.loc[req_pos_unique[i]]["count"]))
                for i, pos_df in enumerate(req_pos_dfs)]
pos_dfs_rows_comb = [[it for item in sublist for it in item]
                     for sublist in list(itertools.product(*pos_dfs_rows)) ]

# building of result
uniqueDf = pd.DataFrame(index=range(len(pos_dfs_rows_comb)), columns=which_pos_count+["TotalHourlyPay"])
for k, comb in enumerate(pos_dfs_rows_comb):
    rows = [pos_dfs[which_pos[i]].ix[ind] for i, ind in enumerate(comb)]
    tp = pd.concat(rows, axis=1, ignore_index=True).transpose()
    uniqueDf.loc[k, which_pos_count] = list(tp["Name"])
    uniqueDf["TotalHourlyPay"].loc[k] = tp["HourlyPay"].sum()
uniqueDf.sort_values(by="TotalHourlyPay", inplace=True)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to achieve. Thank's so much for continuing to work with me after my original post contained the wrong information. I really appreciate it, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the process I followed.

First, get indicator variables for positions held or missing:

```
position = pd.get_dummies(df['Position']).astype(bool)
not_position = ~pd.get_dummies(df['Position'], prefix='not').astype(bool)
df1 = pd.concat([df, position, not_position], axis=1)
```

Next, produce the possible combinations:

```
df2 = df1.merge(df1, left_on='Programmer', right_on='not_Programmer', suffixes=['', '_y'])
df3 = df2.merge(df1, left_on='Supervisor', right_on='not_Supervisor', suffixes=['', '_z'])
```

Then, remove the duplicates and extract the fields that are still relevant

```
df4 = df3[(df3['Analyst']) & (df3['Programmer_y']) & (df3['Supervisor_z'])]
df4.loc[:, ['Name', 'Name_y', 'Name_z', 'HourlyPay', 'HourlyPay_y', 'HourlyPay_z']]
    Name Name_y Name_z  HourlyPay  HourlyPay_y  HourlyPay_z
0   John   Mike   Lisa       15.0         18.0        16.75
1  Frank   Mike   Lisa       15.5         18.0        16.75
```

After that, you can take the sum across the rows, delete the newly useless pay columns, and rename the columns remaining to return an output like your uniqueDf.